# Modifying a managed bean called from an XPiNC : modifications don't show up

Tags: xpages, managed-bean, xpinc

On an XPiNC, a SSJS button calls a Java method defined in a managed bean (don't ask, not mine).

I alter this method. No big deal, basic Java stuff.

I clean/rebuild : the first test results in error 500. After exiting Notes and Designer, no more error, but the behaviour is as if I had made no modification. Something persists somewhere and I can't figure out what, where nor why.

This database is on a server. "Build automatically" is off.

Two weeks ago I ran into the same problem, that sort of solved itself overnight. Now I've been stuck there for a couple of days.

Comment: Do you test your code in the same notes session as your Designer ?

Comment: Yep, what else ? Have another client, another machine, another id ? At what point would it make a difference ?

Comment: Might be some cache issues?

Answer (score 0):

Building the application will delete the class files used by Domino Designer and Notes Client (the latter for XPiNC). That results in the error 500. It's standard behaviour. If you want to test changes you make for an XPiNC application, you will need to close and re-open Notes and Designer before testing each building each change (with build automatically switched off, you only update the .java files, not the .class files the application actually uses). This is why I would not recommend performing initial testing on XPiNC, but in a browser.

There were issues with updating Java in some 8.x releases. I'm not sure which version you're on.

The fact that the application is on a server is not relevant for XPiNC. By default, the application is still run locally in XPiNC, unless the "Run server-based XPages apps directly on server" option is ticked.

[image]

Because the application is on a server, I would recommend testing on a browser. That will identify if the problem is your application or XPiNC.

**UPDATE**

The Package Explorer will let you see the .class files, by amending the filter to include ".* resources", which can be modified as in the screenshot below.

[image: Package Explorer]

Comment: Thanks. I'm on 9.01. btw.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on 9.01. btw.

I would understand that *cleaning* removes the .class files, however I immediately follow by a *build* : isn't that supposed precisely create those .class ? Is there any way I could directly observe those files ?

Comment: However, my problem is not with the XPage per se, which is fairly basic and which I left untouched. No, it's with a managed bean, defining a  class, a method of which I modified. I would expect this class.java to correspond to a .class file.

Comment: I would suspect the later is not recompiled, or at least is cached somewhere in a manner that prevents the new version to be immediately, if ever, available to the client. Strangely enough, I made a simplifid mockup of the same chain in a distinct database on a different server and I was not able to reprocuce the problem.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to access the .class files

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, my changes didn't produce anything visible ... because they failed. Basic Java mistake of a method returning a result even after an exception was rised and trapped. I guess I didn't monitor `xpages.log` close enough.

Also got a more fluid workflow after reactivating autobuild, although I was advised against it and saw several posts to that effect here and there. What gives ? What does "Build automatically" does better than manually rebuilding after cleaning ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to clean every time, building should be enough. The problem with Build Automatically is related to remote servers and source control management. If working on anything other than a local server, builds need to update multiple files on the server - the .class files. If network latency occurs, that can be a pain. Plus it can cause problems if accessing live systems. In standard web app development, your development IDE and source control IDE (e.g. SourceTree) work nicely together. But Domino Designer's sync to ODP and SourceTree "fight" over control of the ODP files.